# Finding key algorithm based on a lot of seed-key pairs

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

I have a question on finding algorithm on seed-key pairs. I have finite data set of seed-key pairs (at this moment about 30000 proper seed-key pairs). Seeds and keys are 16bit (so I have 0xFFFF possibilities of seed-key pairs).

Is it possible to find algorithm/function of key creation from seed? It is not a problem to get more data as I have access to this system and unlimited testing possibility. At this moment I have about 50% of all seed-key pairs.

Is there is any software which can help in that?

Comment: This is a hard problem in general, and off-topic in stackoverflow. Please read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't think this is off-topic. If yes - Then sorry for that. Even when I'll have near 100% of seed-key pairs it is hard?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18266970/2128327

Comment: You may try to use `MATLAB`. However, most probably it will not help you. Try to put the seed key pairs in Excel and try to find a pattern. Post the pairs that you have and see if someone can help you.